# Spring Batch 5 with Cassandra DB

Tags: cassandra, spring-batch, spring-data-cassandra, spring-batch-tasklet, spring-batch-job-monitoring

Sorry I'm totally new to "Spring Batch".
My requirement is , I need to create Spring Batch 5 project which reads rows from cassandra db (Lest say records of particular status in a table), process it (Resend kafka notification, update status and timestamp) and write it back to cassandra db.

I couldn't find any article that use spring batch with cassandra except this
https://github.com/mohdnadeemakhtar/Spring-Batch-with-Cassandra

**I couldn't provide "Datasource" for cassandra db. Is that really possible to acheive my requirement?
Do we have any other suggestions than "Spring Batch"?
**

I need to create a jar of this app and schedule it as a job that runs for every 15min/30min in server. (For now not much to bather about this section)

I tried to provide cassandra config by extending "AbstactCassandraConfiguration" with Spring batch 3.*.* version before this, but that too didn't work out well!

Answer (score 0):

> **That really possible to acheive my requirement?**

It is totally possible.

**Do we have any other suggestions than "Spring Batch"?**

I would isolate third parties integrations (Cassandra / Kafka) from the runtime itself.

For the runtime, Spring Batch would work. You can also consider a Spring camel application. It provides [all connectivity and pollers.](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/cql-component.html#_spring_boot_auto_configuration)

**Cassandra connectivity**

You will rely on Spring Data Cassandra.

You can create extend from `AbstractCassandraConfiguration` or create your own `CqlSession` bean providing the informations (ip, port, credentials, keyspace...). Cassandra is not a relational database and using Datasources or JDBC is definitively not the recommended way.

The link you [shared](https://github.com/mohdnadeemakhtar/Spring-Batch-with-Cassandra) is pretty good (except use of JDBC not required).  What is the error with AbstractCassandraConfiguration on Cassandra connectivity? Here some [explanations](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-cassandra-tutorial)

To create a custom CqlSession bean [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/cassandra-datastax-java-driver) is a great resource.